# BackboneJS: Map RESTful URL to old-school HTTP Query URL

Tags: backbone.js

I've just picked up BackboneJS for a work experiment. We are implementing a whole slew of web-apps on our platform so using a JS framework would simplify a lot of stuff. However, the way to query the server is to use regular HTTP query strings appended to back of a script name; for example, getSomething?id=0&name=2. Basically I am wondering if it is possible in backbone (or, if someone can recommend another popular framework, that one) to map something like /getSomething/:id/:name to the HTTP query string basically making it /service/rest/getSomething?id=:id&name=:name.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Note: I'm thinking maybe I can use the *splat to do this, but that seems kind of ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone doesn't actually require you to use REST and the like with its models. If you decide to skip that, they still offer the ability for you to update models using the .set() to assign a new set of values you retrieve via another method. I've actually got several models where I may hit .fetch() on the model, but it will perform one or several calls to the server to get data and set it back onto the model. Our back end services just don't happen to be a nice fit to the sync setup backbone expects for its built in saving and fetching of models.

Small clarification: I should say that what I've done here is override the "fetch" function on my models with an alternate implementation that uses jQuery $.ajax() calls.

I'm not sure about the whole question you asked originally though with respect to mapping URLs. The URLs that the Backbone router takes are pulled apart and you get the individual pieces. I wouldn't anticipate the router ever making a direct call to the back end though, I would expect that the router would pass those through to a call on the model, which would then interface with the service to get data. Thus only the model layer sees the backend details of the services and any data mapping necessary, the router and the views stay clean of those kind of details.

Comment: Thanks. You cleared up a bunch of stuff. It looks like I am going to have to mess around with a bit this weekend. It seems like it would be a perfect fit for our app development - it's just a matter of bootstrapping a basic project; that is the real hump to get over.

Can you give an example of the fetch in a Model? Every tutorial I have come across for working with external server data has done it by returning a Model based on the returned JSON in the router.

I was following this tutorial pretty close fwiw: http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/